# How does a sub-query work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

As we are familiar with the common syntax:

```
select col1 from tab1 t1 where not exists(select col2 from tab2 t2 where t2.col2 > t1.col1)
select col1 from tab1 t1 where not exists(select col2 from tab2 t2 where t2.col2 < t1.col1)
```

let's now have a simple table named **tab**:

```
    col
----------

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6


----------
```

Now let's query:

```
select col from tab t1 where not exists(select col from tab t2 where t2.col < t1.col)
```

This query results in:1

```
select col from tab t1 where not exists(select col from tab t2 where t2.col > t1.col)
```

This query results in:6

So,I am trying to understand how MySQL does this? I lack theoretical knowledge on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "this query results in:6" and "this query results in:1"

Comment: I mean the output basrd on the given table @Jaan

Comment: @rosemary i replicated your "setup" and ran the query and the results were the other way around (what is also the logical result)

Comment: sorry typing mistake in hurry @ITroubs I am curious to know how the records are compared from one table to the other ..

Comment: @rosemary i explained in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your query

```
select col from tab t1 where not exists(select col from tab t2 where t2.col < t1.col)
```

the

```
select col from tab t1
```

selects all entries then the subquery in

```
where not exists(select col from tab t2 where t2.col < t1.col)
```

selects every entry that is smaller than the current entry it wants to comapre with. So for the entry 1 in the first query it takes no entry since there is no entry that is smaller than 1. then the

```
not exists()
```

kicks in and since there is no result from the subquery, the not exists is true and the whole query returns the 1.

Any other value will not be returned since for any other value you will get a result in the subquery thus leaving the `not exists()` with the value `false`

Comment: The second query is the same just the other way around since there is no bigger element than 6.
Btw. in artificial inteligence or more precise in constraint solving systems this query represents a certain constraint.

Comment: Great tutorial! thank you @itroubs